# Problema al comprobar token en localstorage y login

Tags: reactjs, promesas, local-storage, callback, usestate

Tengo este código que me valida que sección o componente debo mostrar según la condición, sin embargo cuando hago uso del método **onSubmit** de un formulario, envío los datos a un método que se comunica a una API y valida los datos, cuando recibo la respuesta mediante una promesa, el componente no se renderiza y no cambia a la sección automáticamente, debo escribir en la URL la sección o pagina donde quiero estar, por ejemplo: *localhost:3000/home*.

Muestro un ejemplo de mi código junto con la condición que valida las direcciones y los muestra en pantalla:

```
import { token } from "./AccessService"
import React, { useState } from "react"

const App = () => {
  //Recibe como parámetro el token guardado y devuelve true o false si está o no en el localstorage.
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(token);

  //Tiene como parámetro la sección donde está el usuario actualmente y renderiza la sección
  //que le pasen como parámetro según el usuario cambie clickee entre componentes
  const [section, setSection] = useState (() =>{
    const { pathname } = window.location;
    const section = pathname.slice(1);
    return section;
  });

  const toSection = section => event => { //Método que acciona el rendirizado de componentes a través
                                         //de la variable de estado
    event.preventDefault()

    window.history.pushState(null, '', `/${section}`) //Esta línea de código hace posible que el usuario
                                                      //recargue la páginao o vuelva hacia atrás y quede
                                                      //justo en la página donde estaba y no en Home
    setSection(section)
  }

  const getContent = () => {
   const SECTION_TYPE = Object.freeze({
     HOME: 'home',
     USER: 'user',
     LOGIN: 'login',
  })


  //Esta condición valida que componente mostrar según el valor de la variable section 
  //que va cambiando según el componente
  if(auth && section === SECTION_TYPE.HOME){
     return (
       <>
         <Home toSection = {toSection} />
       </>
     );
    }else if(auth && section === SECTION_TYPE.USER){
       return (
         <>
           <UserList toSection = {toSection} />
         </>
       );
    }else {
       return (
         <>
           <LogIn setAuth = {setAuth} toSection = {toSection} />
         </>
       );
     }
    }

   return(
     <>
       {getContent()}
     </>
    );
}
```

El método login corresponde a un services que tengo definido de la siguiente manera:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const token = localStorage.getItem('myThreePicsToken');

const loginSession = async (user, pass) => {
  try {
      const headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      };

      const response = await axios.post(
          "https://three-points.herokuapp.com/api/login",
          `{"username":"${user}", "password":"${pass}"}`,
          { headers: headers }
      );

      if (response.data.token) {
          localStorage.setItem("myThreePicsToken", response.data.token);
          return response.data.token;
      } else {}
          return "";
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response)
      }
      return "";
  }
}

export default loginSession;
```

En este services **exporto el token que sirve como valor al estado del componente central App.jsx que mediante comprobar si el token está en el localstorage me muestra directamente Home y si el token no está me muestra login**.

Por último el componente donde tengo el formulario de Login:

```
import loginSession from "./AccessService"

const LogIn = ({ setAuth, toSection }) => {
  return(
    <>
      <main className='d-flex form-size'>
         <section className='container d-flex flex-column section-center'>
              <div>
                  <h3>Log In</h3>
              </div>
                <form className="form-center"
                   onSubmit={ event => {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      const form = event.target;
                        loginSession( form.user.value, form.pass.value )
                        .then(() => {
                            setAuth(true)
                            toSection('home')
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            alert('An error occurred: '+ error)
                         })
                     }}
                >
<div className="mb-3">
 <input type="user" name='user' className="form-control" id="user" aria-describedby="userHelp" placeholder="User ID"/>
</div>
<div className="mb-3">
 <input type="password" name='pass' className="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
<div id="userHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your information with anyone else.</div>
</div>

                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" />LOGIN</button>
                  </form>
              </section>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}

export default LogIn;
```

**Lo que no logro hacer es que el usuario al logearse correctamente pase a la página home y si el token que guarda el código ya está en el localstorage pase automáticamente a home.**

Nota:
Como pueden ver no estoy usando React Router, el ejercicio que estoy haciendo no implementa Router al momento.